# Extra space in directive attributes in html template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I noticed a weird thing when I was writing an angular directive. In the isolated scope of the directive, if I bind an attribute using `myAttr: '@'` to the parent scope variable with the same name, and then use that attribute in the html template, there will be an extra space trailing the attribute value. If the attribute is bound to the parent scope variable with a different name using `myAttr: '@thatAttr'`, however, there is no extra space and the world is happy.

Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EEpv2/2/) for a demonstration. As you can see, the css rules under `div[bad=foo]` is not applied because of the extra space, while `div[good=bar]` is perfectly fine.

The fiddle uses Angular 1.3 by the way. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: seen this in markup before, has never been a problem for me. I don't think it's just isolated to case you pointed out either.  Also seems to be consistent across multiple versions  http://plnkr.co/edit/MppW1TY4g8QfRaGQs6pc

Comment: You should assign a variable to `foo`, so the `foo` should be declared as variable in your controller like `$scope.foo = 'foo'`

Comment: Seems like a bug in angular. I would have expected the same as you. If you pass bad="{{foo}}" in your HTML, and foo is bound to "bad" (no spaces) on your scope, then I would have expected it to render as bad="bad". But instead, angular is rendering bad="bad " with the extra space. If this hasn't been reported to the angular team, it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8132) in Angular, likely will not be fixed

Comment: I guess there's no motivation to fix it since 'replace' has been deprecated. Still, there are those stuck with 1.2 because of IE8 - they should fix it.

Comment: Angular is still to be considered a young project where API changes like this can happen, they are obviously now concentrating on 1.3 / 2.0 versions. Anyway, your jsFiddle seems work as expected when you remove `replace: true` line, so try to live without it in your _real_ app

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - I added "@id" as an attribute in m Directive. That worked - however it inserted me an additional blank space at the end of the id value.

It turned out that Angular takes over the id by default! After removing "@id" from the scope attributes of my directive, I could use "{{id}}" without any problems.